# SSL connection could not be established

Tags: c#, http, ssl, httpclient

I've got an issue with sending HTTP requests to as part of automation testing, I want to check URL's status code. When I send the request I have an Exception:

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)'

The inner exceptions are:

> HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

> SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

My code:

```
    public HttpStatusCode SendRequest(string _url)
    {
        SetUrl(_url);

        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
        clientHandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);

        var response = client.GetAsync(Url).Result;

        StatusCode = response.StatusCode;

        return StatusCode;
    }
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Which version of Windows and .Net do you have? Which version of TLS does the server have?

Comment: @Charlieface Windows 10, .NET Core 5.0 And regarding the TLS, I don't really know because it's external company that provides us Security solutions.

Comment: Open it in a browser, and view the security info by clicking the lock symbol next to the URL

Comment: @Charlieface I saw there V3 .. does it means SSL 3.0 ?

Answer (score 3):

As @CodeCaster already mentioned: `SslProtocols.Tls` (TLS 1.0) is not an option nowadays. Simply use `SslProtocols.None` (which is the default) to let the OS choose the best option for you:

> None: Allows the operating system to choose the best protocol to use, and to block protocols that are not secure. Unless your app has a specific reason not to, you should use this field.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols?view=net-5.0#fields

Furthermore skipping the server certificate validation (by letting `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` just return true) is a very dangerous thing. You should avoid that.

Is the remote host under your control? Can you check which TLS version it's using?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, If it it only for automation, there is no other way to pass this ?

Answer (score 1):

The remote host does (rightfully) not accept that you want to connect using TLS 1.0, which is deprecated.

Specify .Tls12 or .Tls13.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried it and unfortunately that does not work also.